# canShareVia invokes the success callback when it should not - iOS 11.2

Tags: facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, socialshare

**Description**

When the Facebook app is not installed, canShareVia method should invoke the error callback, which is working perfectly with my iPhone5s running iOS 10.

When I test it on iPhone5s running iOS 11.2, it is always invoking the success callback in both the cases where the Facebook app is installed and Not installed.

**App**

A Cordova mobile app

Plugin: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

**Device information**

- iPhone 5s
- iOS 11.2
- Facebook app: Not installed

**Sample code**

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.canShareVia('com.apple.social.facebook', 'msg', null, null, null, 
function(success) {
   do some stuff....
}, function(error) {
   alert(error); 
});
```

Please let me know if any work around has been found.

---

**Updated**

Found the cause:

> This [plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin) always returns true since iOS11. So we might need another way to detect if there is an app installed and available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get it to work with [cordova-plugin-appavailability](https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability).

You can implement this way (Appavailability plugin to check Facebook app availability and social sharing plugin to do the actual sharing).

```
appAvailability.check(
    'fb://',
    function() {  // Success callback
        window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaFacebook(...)
    },
    function() {  // Error callback
        console.log('Facebook App is not available');
    }
);
```

Though this is a work around but not a fix, this is the only way for now until the fix gets merged to [cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin).

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answer for your question here.
[App Availability](https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability).
Read this and your requirement will be piece of cake.